# How to find the output and input impedance of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance

For example:

### [image]

Vcc -> GND

capacitors -> wires

NPNs -> hi and current source

The schematic above becomes:

[image]

How can you find the output and the input impedance?

The answer in this case should be(output impedance):

[image]

I guess hi1=hi2 since it's the same transistor

Comment: You need to clean up your schematic.  Particularly the first one is annoying to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "tricks" to answering those questions with transistor amplifiers.

The first trick is to understand that the current-transfer ratio (*h<sub>FE</sub>*) of a transistor effectivly multiplies the resistance at its emitter. So, to find the impedance looking into the base, you calculate the effective resistance at its emitter, multiply this by *h<sub>FE</sub>*, and then add the internal base resistance.

The second trick is to realize that the result of the calculation above is typically orders of magnitude larger than the other resistances connected to the base of the transistor and can therefore be ignored. In other words, the input impedance of a transistor amplifier is usually very close to the impedance of its bias network alone. Indeed, bias networks are very often designed so that this is the case.

The output impedance is a question of how much the output voltage changes with output current: ΔV/ΔI. The transistor itself is essentially a current source, and whatever current it is passing is shared between the various resistances connected to the emitter. Therefore, the output impedance is equal to the net emitter resistance, not including the resistance of the external load.

Comment: "Therefore, the output impedance is equal to the net emitter resistance, not including the resistance of the external load"  -  which emitter resistance? of the second transistor(closest to the output) or the product of both emitter resistances?

Comment: Just the second stage. The fact that each transistor functions as a current source effectively hides any effects of "upstream" impedances.

Comment: @DaveTweed  The trick to proving Zout is back driving the output voltage different from the output being tested for impedance. If the load regulation is 1% then the output impedance is 1% of the load. Or if 50% then the load matches the source.  So the emitter Follower is not just Re but also Rs/hFE in parallel. Just as a grounded common base is near 0 ohms AC coupled into the emitter for small signals.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already entered the schematic into LTSpice, the easiest way is to use the simulator. For each port (here you have two ports, input and output) that you care about,

- Add a load termination on the other port representing how it will be used in a bigger circuit.
- Add an AC current source to the port you are testing. Give this source an amplitude of "1".
- Add a net name to the net at the port you are testing (for example "VIN" or "VOUT").
- Run an AC simulation over the frequency range you are interested in.
- Plot the voltage at the port you are testing.

Because your AC source has a value of 1, the voltage you plot is equal (at 1 ohm per volt) to the equivalent input/output impedance at that port. Never mind that in reality a 1 A current source would drive your circuit into all kinds of nonlinear behavior. A SPICE AC simulation uses a strictly linearized version of the circuit and won't include any nonlinear behavior.

Note that this method works even if you don't approximate the capacitors with wires. In fact, if you don't, it will let you see the effect those capacitors have on the in/output impedance at frequencies below where they are well-approximated by wires.

Second, if you have simulator models for the transistors, you don't even have to reduce the transistors to their ac-equivalent model. The simulator will do this for you. It will also include parasitic capacitances in the transistor so that you know whether the transistor has adequate response at the frequencies you're using for the simple model to be accurate.